# c# clickOnce xml file not found

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, publish

C# deployment clicOnce. Setup run xml file not found?

```
  XDocument x = XDocument.Load(@"veri.xml");
```

image1:
http://www.kgmmp.org/333.jpg

[image]

Comment: You're including a file directly from the `bin\Debug` directory. Is your ClickOnce deployment using a Debug build..?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file in the project, check whether it is **copy local** from the file's properties. file  must be **copy local**. then you can try the following.

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Load(@"veri.xml");
```

```
    string filePath = Path.Combine(
    HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, 
    @"App_Data\AppSettings.xml"
);
```

Comment: Hocam galiba Türksünüz? projeyi yayınlayınca diğer makinalarda xml dosyası bulunamadı hatası alıyorum. Yardımcı olurmusunuz.

Comment: yes, I have to write in english. you may need to check the paths of the files. Do you write which path on the other servers stand?

Comment: I edited my comment try this. You can use server path for your xml file

Comment: I don't think you can use `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` for a ClickOnce application, as that runs on the desktop and not in web hosting..